# Discord bot не хочет проигрывать музыку с YouTube

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, бот, discord.py

```
main.py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import music

# Инициализация бота
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='/', intents = discord.Intents.all())

# Добавляем к объекту бота команды в виде методов
cogs = [music]
for i in range(len(cogs)):
    cogs[i].setup(client)

#запуск бота
client.run("TOKEN")






music.py

import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import youtube_dl


# Создаем класс 'music', который является подклассом 'Cog'
class music(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.command()
    async def join(self, ctx):  # команда покдючения в голосовой канал
        if ctx.author.voice is None:  # если автор команды не в канале,
            await ctx.send('Войди в канал для начала')  # то просим войти
        ch = ctx.message.author.voice.channel  # переменная канала автора
        if ctx.voice_client is None:  # если бот не подключен к голосовому,
            await ch.connect()  # то подключись
        else:
            await ctx.voice_client.move_to(ch)  # перейди в нужный канал

    @commands.command()  # команда выхода из голосового канала
    async def leave(self, ctx):
        await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()

    @commands.command()
    async def play(self, ctx, url):  # команда воспроизведения музыки, в параметры добавляем ссылку на видео
        ctx.voice_client.stop()  # если музыка уже играла, то остановится
        FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1\
         -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}  # опции ffmpeg, стандартные для стрима
        YDL_OPTIONS = {'format': 'bestaudio'}  # видео(ютуб) сконвертируем в аудио

        with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:  # переменная, хранящая опции загрузки данных из видео
            info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)  # извлекаем информацию из ссылки, само видео НЕ скачиваем
            url2 = info['formats'][0]['url']  # создаем ссылку для аудиопотока
            # создаем стрим для воспроизведения, получаем информацию о битрейде и кодеке
            source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(url2, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS)
            # и транслируем прямо в канал
            ctx.voice_client.play(source)

    @commands.command()  # команда остановки
    async def pause(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send('Пауза')
        await ctx.voice_client.pause()

    @commands.command()  # команда возобновления
    async def resume(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send('Продолжаем')
        await ctx.voice_client.resume()


def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(music(client))  # регистрируем коги`введите сюда код`







Error
```

Ignoring exception in command play:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\Python_2_lvl\proj\DiscordBot\MusicBot\music.py", line 27, in play
ctx.voice_client.stop()  # если музыка уже играла, то остановится
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'stop'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 863, in invoke
await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'stop'

Answer (score 2):

Если я не ошибаюсь, то такую возможность заблокировали. Из-за этого многие "музыкальные" боты лягли.

Answer (score 0):

Дискорд уже давно заблокировал возможность использовать данный сервис в ботах, попробуй через яндекс музыку и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте в файле "youtube.py" (`C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\extractor\youtube.py`) библиотеки "youtube_dl" закомментировать 1794 строку: `'uploader_id': self._search_regex(r'/(?:channel|user)/([^/?&#]+)', owner_profile_url, 'uploader id') if owner_profile_url else None,`.
Увидел данное решение на YouTube, но не знаю как долго это ещё будет работать.